# jquery plugin banning on azure websites

Tags: azure, jquery-plugins

I have a funny feeling that when deploying some jquery plugins with a MVC4 project to azure websites that these plugins are somehow banned - Can this be true?

For instance I'm using http://css-tricks.com/moving-boxes/, but it seems that the file is missing after deployed to azure. I'm not trying to do any illegal stuff here, so I'll stop using the plugin if I'm not allowed to, since I haven't coded the thing...

But it would be nice to know if my suspicion is true or far fetched, before I stop using it or go nutch...

Morten

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You assumption is far fetched :). I would check that your JavaScript isn't being bundled at build time which is why you're not seeing the file in any requests when the resulting solution has been deployed to Azure.

Comment: Thank you for you answer!
But I'm not sure what you mean! The plugin is being bundled, as my other JS files. In BundleConfig.cs I've added:

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery.movingboxes").Include("~/Scripts/jquery.movingboxes.js"));

Inorder to being  able to call: 

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery.movingboxes") on the page... Is this a wrong way to think or should it be setup some other way?
I've other plugins where this setup seems to work fine...

Comment: Bundling combines all your scripts into one - this is why you are not seeing a separate file.  Perhaps this is a caching issue?